# Boundary sharing line featureclassess

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcmap

[image]In my data I have to remove some line feature classes, which are those sharing boundaries with two states i.e. New York and Philadelphia.

I have to remove all data of Philadelphia but some feature classes cross the border and fall in New York.

How can I remove those line featureclasses which are in Philadelphia but share a boundary with New York?

attaching screenshot, that might help.

!light pink colour is New Hampshire  and blue line are going toward white colour MA

Comment: When did Philadelphia get promoted to be a state? Providing a graphic with the data sources might provide more background than just words (and give a better idea of the topology classes involved).  It may also help to specify the service pack of ArcGIS 10.0 (which is quite old now), which level of software you have available (ArcInfo/ArcEditor/ArcView), and the format of the feature classes (shapefile/FGDB/ArcSDE). Use the "edit" button to add this information.

Comment: I think we will need to see a picture illustrating the situation that you are trying to describe in words.  There is an edit button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.